# loop through pandas dataset one day at a time

Tags: python, pandas

I was curious if someone could give me a tip on how to break a pandas dataframe down between a train & test dataset (for machine learning on *time series*)

AND

Add consecutively days to the training dataset one day at a time by a for loop. For example, first run would be just the training dataset. Second run would be the training data + day 1 of the test dataset. Third run to train a model would be the training data + day 1 + day 2 etc... And so on hopefully that makes sense

Basically the training dataset builds day by day for each day in the test dataset.

Trying to do that here:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



#load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbartling/Data/master/df_delta.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df = df[['Delta']]
df['Date_time'] = df.index.astype('datetime64[ns]')



print('first Date')
first_date = df.Date_time.min()
print(first_date)

print('last Date')
last_date = df.Date_time.max()
print(last_date)

df = df.drop(['Date_time'],axis=1)



test_df = df.copy()
test_df = test_df.loc[test_df.index.month.isin([6,7,8,9,10])]

train_df = df.drop(df.index[df.index.month.isin([6,7,8,9,10])])



#loop through each day in dataset
for idx, days in test_df.groupby(test_df.index.date):

        #get current date
        Day = days.index.day[0]
        Month = days.index.month[0]
        Year = days.index.year[0]


        this_day_date = str(Year) + '-' + str(Month) + '-' + str(Day)
        print(this_day_date)


        need_to_train = (df.index > first_date) & (df.index <= this_day_date)
        #need_to_train = df.loc[start_date:end_date]


        #check to make sure loop is coming through 24 hours of data at a time
        print('number of hours in dataset to train on this loop: ',len(need_to_train))
```

I know I dont have the idea quite correct, but when I run the code Im only getting the first day of data `4249`. What I am hoping to see if this build by a value of 24 at a time. (24 hours in a day for the hourly data)

```
2020-10-11
number of hours in dataset to train on this loop:  4249
2020-10-12
number of hours in dataset to train on this loop:  4249
2020-10-13
number of hours in dataset to train on this loop:  4249
2020-10-14
number of hours in dataset to train on this loop:  4249
2020-10-15
number of hours in dataset to train on this loop:  4249
2020-10-16
number of hours in dataset to train on this loop:  4249
2020-10-17
number of hours in dataset to train on this loop:  4249
2020-10-18
number of hours in dataset to train on this loop:  4249
2020-10-19
number of hours in dataset to train on this loop:  4249
2020-10-20
number of hours in dataset to train on this loop:  4249
2020-10-21
number of hours in dataset to train on this loop:  4249
>>>
```

Comment: cant you concat prev day with today in an iteration? Alternate, just use a date and increment. cutoff any data post that date from the full dataset. That way you have the dataset you need.

Comment: to answer your first part: `sklearn train_test_split`

Answer (score 0):

this works `need_to_train = df.loc[first_date:this_day_date]`

Full script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



#load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbartling/Data/master/df_delta.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df = df[['Delta']]
df['Date_time'] = df.index.astype('datetime64[ns]')



print('first Date')
first_date = df.Date_time.min()
print(first_date)

print('last Date')
last_date = df.Date_time.max()
print(last_date)

df = df.drop(['Date_time'],axis=1)



test_df = df.copy()
test_df = test_df.loc[test_df.index.month.isin([6,7,8,9,10])]

train_df = df.drop(df.index[df.index.month.isin([6,7,8,9,10])])



#loop through each day in dataset
for idx, days in test_df.groupby(test_df.index.date):

        #get current date
        Day = days.index.day[0]
        Month = days.index.month[0]
        Year = days.index.year[0]


        this_day_date = str(Year) + '-' + str(Month) + '-' + str(Day)
        print(this_day_date)


        #need_to_train = (df.index > first_date) & (df.index <= this_day_date)
        need_to_train = df.loc[first_date:this_day_date]


        #check to make sure loop is coming through 24 hours of data at a time
        print('number of hours in dataset to train on this loop: ',len(need_to_train))
```